# ‎Intune enrolment option for a shared windows device

Tags: intune

What is the best method to enroll and autopilot a single device shared by multiple Azure ad users in Intune?

What option is most widely used, in terms of enrolment, app distribution, this will only be Azure AD joined

1. Use user-driven autopilot enrolment - get one user to enroll the device in INtune with autopilot and then sign out from the device (not from the Company portal app/ work school account - just the machine) then the rest of the users use another user option and login with there Az AD creds.
2. Use Shared multi-user config profile - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/shared-user-device-settings
3. Kiosk Multi app

Thanks !!